# Why is "[FromBody]string json" null when coming from Postman?

Tags: c#, .net, api, postman

When I call this API method from my unit test, the `json` parameter has a value.  But when I do it from Postman, it's always null.

```
/// <summary>
/// Save the access integration settings for a given integration.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="json"></param>
/// <param name="integrationID"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
[Route("api/AccessIntegrationSettings/{integrationID}")]
[SwaggerOperation(Tags = new[] { "Access Integration: Integration Settings" })]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]string json, string integrationID)
{
    ....
}
```

Here's what I'm doing in Postman (pictures are easier...)

[image]

For headers, there are two security headers (which are not the issue) and this one too:

```
Content-Type    application/json
```

I'm not sure if I have my method improperly configured, or if my call from Postman is wrong.  But again, when I hit this method from a unit test, the `json` parameter has a value, so I'm inclined to think that I'm doing something wrong in Postman, but I don't know what.

**UPDATE:**

I've also noticed that if I validate the ModelState, it's always `true` when coming from the unit test, and always `false` when coming from Postman.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
     if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
     {
         ....
     }
}
```

If I drill into the ModelState from each call, there is an extra key-value pair when coming from Postman that isn't there when coming from my unit test:

```
key:   json
value: null
```

Comment: Postman is sending json, not a string. If you really want a string and not the "right way" per @lucky, then enclose the data in quotes (escape all internal quotes) and set the content type to text/plain.

Comment: Ok ok this is making sense.  But in Postman if I change keep it Raw and change the type to Text and wrap it all in quotes, I get the same error.  My guess is I need to escape all the double quotes within the json?

Comment: Yes, try with just a simple string to see if it comes in.

Comment: yes, a simple string works, as does escaping all the double quotes in the json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use parameter binding, `Asp.Net` would deserialize the json instead of you.

So, try to use complex object in action parameters.

```
public class SampleJson
{
    public bool IntegrationEnabled { get; set; }

    public bool SyncUsers { get; set; }

    //etc...
}
```

Also, add `HttpPost` attribute for your action.

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post(SampleJson jsonObject, [FromUri]string integrationID)
```

**EDIT**

If you want to handle multiple types, you can merge the objects like this;

```
public class RootJson
{
    public SampleJson SampleJson { get; set; }

    public AnotherSampleJson AnotherSampleJson { get; set; }
}
```

And you can check simple null control for that properties.

> Note : Keep in mind that, merging the complex objects changes the json. It should be surrounded with root brackets.

Comment: Ok,  And if this method will be used for multiple types?  I want to keep it generic because we have no idea what type of object will be passed.  The client will know, and it can then deserlaize.  But for our purposes, we just need to be able to pass a string.

Comment: for your edit, would you also need to change the method definition?

Comment: Yes, the method parameter should be RootJson instead of SampleJson.

Comment: And one last question: If we end up adding more types in the future (which absolutely will happen) is there some way to not have to alter the code?  I'm leaning more towards what Crowcoder suggested in the comments as a more long term solution.

Comment: But you will deserialize the posted json anyway right ? You will create complex object to represent new json. I don't know do you have any idea about it but if it like this, you should alter the code anyway.